# Container with child height

Tags: flutter

I have a column which have multiple containers as children, i want the containers height to be the child's height. am doing this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(''),
                        Container(
                          child: WebView(
                              initialUrl:'',
                              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                        ),
                        Text(''),
                        Container(
                          child: WebView(
                              initialUrl:'',
                              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                        ),
                        Text(''),
                        Container(
                          child: WebView(
                              initialUrl:'',
                              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ))
```

but this returns this error:

> All FlutterError objects should have only a single short (one line) summary description of the problem that was detected.
>   MalformedFlutterError
>     RenderSemanticsGestureHandler object was given an infinite size during layout.
>
> This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

If i added height to the container it will work fine, but i don't want to add the height i want it to take its height.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` for Column

Comment: I think you need to define the height because of the container child is WebView, dont know exactly about the WebView but I think it has infinite height, and Container always following the size of the child, you can try to change the child of the Container into some fixed size widget like Text, and you wont need to add the height to the Container

Answer (score 0):

Condition 1: Remove SingleChildScrollView and use Expanded flex take cell phone full screen height, see full code 1

Conition 2 : With SingleChildScrollView and Wrap with Container set long height such as 2000,  take related height and scrollable, see full code 2

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: 2000,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(''),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                ),
              ),
```

Condition 1 full code 1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(''),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
            ),
          ),
          Text(''),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                child: WebView(
                    initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
              )),
          Text(''),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Condition 2 full code 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: 2000,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(''),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                ),
              ),
              Text(''),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    child: WebView(
                        initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                  )),
              Text(''),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]